# JQuery replacing image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, interface, jquery-events

I want to extend some JQuery code to replace an image once I click on it.
I have this:

```
var minimiseContent = function(e)
{
    var targetContent = $('div.itemContent', this.parentNode.parentNode);
    if (targetContent.css('display') == 'none') {
        targetContent.slideDown(300);
        var minIcon = $('minimise', this.parentNode.parentNode);
        $(minIcon).attr("src", "../IMG/btnMinimise.png");

    } else {
    targetContent.slideUp(300);
        var minIcon = $('minimise', this.parentNode.parentNode);
        $(minIcon).attr("src", "../IMG/btnMaximise.png");

    }
    return false;
};
```

which is called from this:

```
$('a.minimise').bind('click', minimiseContent);
```

and declared like so:

```
<a href="#" class="minimise"><img src="../IMG/btnMinimise.png" class="minimise" /></a>
```

Essentially the two lines in the first part of the coding should handle it i.e.

```
var minIcon = $('minimise', this.parentNode.parentNode);
            $(minIcon).attr("src", "../IMG/btnMinimise.png");
```

and

```
        var minIcon = $('minimise', this.parentNode.parentNode);
        $(minIcon).attr("src", "../IMG/btnMaximise.png");
```

But I do not know why the image is not replaced. `minimise` is a class in the css file. The rest of the coding works.

I have tried replacing `$(minIcon)` with `$(this)`, `$(img.minimise)`, but none work.
Does anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impression is that you want to replace this:

```
var minIcon = $('minimise', this.parentNode.parentNode);
```

With this:

```
var minIcon = $('img.minimise', this.parentNode.parentNode);
```

Comment: Cheers. I thought I already tried this - as written in my intial post - but it happened to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<a>` tag. The img tag can have a click event as well.

Also, I think this is a good use case for the [toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle) function:

```
$("img.minimise").toggle(
  function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "../IMG/btnMinimise.png")
  },
  function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "../IMG/btnMaximise.png");
  }
);
```

It will alternate function calls on every click.

Comment: Thanks, but I find the behaviour of the toggle is unpredictable. I am using jQuery 1.1.2 so maybe that is the problem? But I can't upgrade. The behavious for instance does many sliding up, and sliding down on one click. Is it possible through the way it is coded in my initial code?